# Vue js UI Stuttering on low end mobile (Grid View scroll) number of grid is only 12, memory consumption is also low

Tags: scroll, vuejs3, css-grid

[Issue Can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4onbr.jpg) [Screenshot from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWFV9.jpg)

When user is scrolling through this grid patchy white screen is happening on lower end phone with 2GB RAM

Similar website like [poki](https://poki.com/) is running fine on the same device

Using Vue js 3 - Composition API - Vuetify - Pinia - axios

```
<div
      :id="index * no_of_tiles + 0"
      :data-game-id="games.games[0].id"
      @click="openInNewTab(games.games[0], games.games, index)"
      class="large-game element"
      v-if="games.games[0]"
    >
      <picture>
        <v-img
          class="large-game-container"
          :src="getLargeGameURL(games.games[0])"
          :alt="games.games[0].name"
        />
        <span class="large-game-name-card">{{ games.games[0].name }}</span>
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div
      v-if="games.games[1]"
      :id="index * no_of_tiles + 1"
      :data-game-id="games.games[1].id"
      @click="openInNewTab(games.games[1], games.games, index)"
      class="small-game-ad-top element"
    >
      <picture>
        <v-img
          class="small-game-container"
          :src="getSmallGameURL(games.games[1])"
          :alt="games.games[1].name"
        />
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div
      :id="index * no_of_tiles + 2"
      :data-game-id="games.games[2].id"
      v-if="games.games[2]"
      @click="openInNewTab(games.games[2], games.games, index)"
      class="small-game-ad-botom element"
    >
      <picture>
        <v-img
          class="small-game-container"
          :src="getSmallGameURL(games.games[2])"
          :alt="games.games[2].name"
        />
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div
      :id="index * no_of_tiles + 3"
      :data-game-id="games.games[3].id"
      v-if="games.games[3]"
      @click="openInNewTab(games.games[3], games.games, index)"
      class="small-game-botom1 element"
    >
      <picture>
        <v-img
          class="small-game-container"
          :src="getSmallGameURL(games.games[3])"
          :alt="games.games[3].name"
        />
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div
      :id="index * no_of_tiles + 4"
      :data-game-id="games.games[4].id"
      v-if="games.games[4]"
      @click="openInNewTab(games.games[4], games.games, index)"
      class="small-game-botom2 element"
    >
      <picture>
        <v-img
          class="small-game-container"
          :src="getSmallGameURL(games.games[4])"
          :alt="games.games[4].name"
        />
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div
      :id="index * no_of_tiles + 5"
      :data-game-id="games.games[5].id"
      v-if="games.games[5]"
      @click="openInNewTab(games.games[5], games.games, index)"
      class="small-game-botom3 element"
    >
      <picture>
        <v-img
          class="small-game-container"
          :src="getSmallGameURL(games.games[5])"
          :alt="games.games[5].name"
        />
      </picture>
    </div>
```

```
.game-section-layout {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(3,26vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,26vw); */
  grid-template-areas:
    "larger larger smaller1"
    "larger larger smaller2"
    "smaller3c smaller3b smaller3a";
  grid-gap: 23px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 11.5px 0px 11.5px 0px;
}
```

I have used vue-virtual-scroller for pagination effort rendering only 4 grids on the screen and still having the same issue

I have also used it as component and in the parent file itself no changes are observed

I have tried with 4 grid and it is working fine anything above that it is causing issue on the low end mobile. It perfectly works mid or high end phone